# How to change PHP version pointed in console to version used by Apache in Windows?

Tags: php

I want command `php -v` to point to my newest version of PHP. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change enviroment variables to point to the newest version.
Open up Control Panel, then navigate to System.
From the left menu select the "Advanced system settings".
In the new window navigate to "Advanced" and on the bottom click "Enviroment Variables". Find the PATH variable in there, and click edit.
Now you want to find the php location in there and change the folder to point to the newer version.

Comment: Working. (But I wonder why it showed, lets say middle, 7.0.4 version if they had to choose 3 versions and enviroment path didn't had any php path till now.)